# Is there a better way to filter this datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, code-cleanup

I have a datagridview that is filtered by a double click event using a switch statement.  The data source is originally set by a LINQ to SQL query based on user input, they then have the option of double clicking on a cell to filter for like items such as model, computer name or operating system.

There just seems like too much duplicated code here.  Any thoughts on a better way of doing this?

```
private void gridInventory_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
            {
                var cell = this.gridInventory[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                var clickedValue = (cell.Value != null) ? cell.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clickedValue))
                {
                    switch (this.gridInventory.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case @"MODEL":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.Model != null && r.Model.ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"COMPUTERNAME":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.ComputerName != null && r.ComputerName.ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"SERIALNUMBER":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.SerialNumber != null && r.SerialNumber.ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"COMPUTERID":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.ComputerID.ToString().ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"MANUFACTURER":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.Manufacturer != null && r.Manufacturer.ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"OSVERSION":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.OSVersion != null && r.OSVersion.ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"AUDITDATE":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.AuditDate != null && r.AuditDate.ToString().ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        case @"AUDITGUID":
                            CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => r.AuditGUID != null && r.AuditGUID.ToString().ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    if (this.CurrentList != null)
                    {
                        gridInventory.DataSource = this.CurrentList;
                        this.lblRecords.Text = string.Format(@"Total Records: {0}", CurrentList.Count(c => c.ComputerID > 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, @"error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ and reflection this function can be rewritten this way:

```
private void gridInventory_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
            {
                var cell = this.gridInventory[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                var clickedValue = (cell.Value != null) ? cell.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clickedValue))
                {
                    CurrentList = CurrentList.Where(r => typeof(r_type_here).GetProperty(this.gridInventory.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name).GetValue(r, null) != null &&
                        typeof(r_type_here).GetProperty(this.gridInventory.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name).GetValue(r, null).ToString().ToUpper() == clickedValue.ToUpper()).ToList();

                    if (this.CurrentList != null)
                    {
                        gridInventory.DataSource = this.CurrentList;
                        this.lblRecords.Text = string.Format(@"Total Records: {0}", CurrentList.Count(c => c.ComputerID > 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, @"error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Replace `r_type_here` with actual type of element from your `CurrentList` and you should get the same result.

**Advantages:**

- Code is shorter
- Code is more flexible - if you want to add new
  column/property then you won't need to write a single line of code
  here

**Disadvantages:**

- You have to maintain character case - i.e. case in property names of list element class should have exactly equal case with corresponding columns' names in `gridInventory.Columns`
- Less readable code
- If you use this function frequently that might become a performance bottleneck - reflection is generally slower than your case statement.

Also a check for proprty exsitence should be implemented in the same LINQ `where` statement.

Comment: Thank you!  This works well.  I like the flexibility this code offers, as we will most likey add columns in the future.  As for the case issue both property names and column names are derived from the same data source, so that shouldnt be an issue.  Thank you again.